# cant display custom meta box data

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

im creating a custom metabox as such:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Relaterade sidor
* Description: lägg till relaterade sidor
* Version: 1.0
* Author: test
* Author URI: test
*
*/


function relaterade_sidor_get_meta( $value ) {
global $post;

$field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value, true );
if ( ! empty( $field ) ) {
    return is_array( $field ) ? stripslashes_deep( $field ) : stripslashes( wp_kses_decode_entities( $field ) );
} else {
    return false;
}
}

function relaterade_sidor_add_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'relaterade_sidor-relaterade-sidor',
    __( 'relaterade sidor', 'relaterade_sidor' ),
    'relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_html',
    'post',
    'normal',
    'default'
);
add_meta_box(
    'relaterade_sidor-relaterade-sidor',
    __( 'relaterade sidor', 'relaterade_sidor' ),
    'relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_html',
    'page',
    'normal',
    'default'
);
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'relaterade_sidor_add_meta_box' );

function relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_html( $post) {
wp_nonce_field( '_relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_nonce', 'relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_nonce' ); ?>

<p>relaterade sidor</p>

<p>
    <label for="relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url"><?php _e( 'Url', 'relaterade_sidor' ); ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url" id="relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url" value="<?php echo relaterade_sidor_get_meta( 'relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url' ); ?>">
</p><?php
}

function relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_save( $post_id ) {
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
if ( ! isset( $_POST['relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_nonce'], '_relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_nonce' ) ) return;
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

if ( isset( $_POST['relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url', esc_attr( $_POST['relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_save' );

/*
Usage: relaterade_sidor_get_meta( 'relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url' )
*/

?>
```

the text remains in the textfield after saving/updating so I guess that means it is saved to the database, but when trying to display the data in a page or post I only get blank.

I tried with both these ones:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

 $intro = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'relaterade_sidor-relaterade-sidor', true);
echo "content: " . $intro;
?>
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'relaterade_sidor-relaterade-sidor', true);
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

But I only get blank, cant get it to display the content saved in the custom meta textbox.

Comment: I did a database search and confirmed that the data is being saved, the trouble must be within displaying the data but cant find where.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, was trying to connect it to the metabox name when i should connect the key,

```
$intro = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'relaterade_sidor_relaterade_sidor_url',    true);
echo "content: " . $intro;
```

works just fine inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest CMB2 library. No more headaches with metaboxes ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31662024/5162081